# Querying AppDefinition returns 10 results with empty key IDs

Tags: soql

When I try to query `AppDefinition` through developer console, it says Total Rows: 10, but only shows one and the id is `000000000000000AAA`.

[image]

When I try to query through `sfdx force:data:soql:query`, Workbench, or Anonymous Apex, I am seeing 10 items with all ids `000000000000000AAA`. (`Label` and `DeveloperName` fields are normal when queried. Same result for production and sandbox orgs)

[image]
Also I am sure there are more than 10 apps in the org that I can access as an admin.

How to query and see all apps with correct ids?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_appdefinition.htm), Id is `default Salesforce ID` and it is the same across all the orgs.

You need to apply the filter on DurableId which is `a unique virtual Salesforce ID for the application`.

[image]